# Configuring Spring Boot Logback

Tags: java, logging, configuration, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to write the `application.yml` file with the logging configurations for spring boot. Thanks to Bal from my previous question I was able to take a look at the [sample file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) on spring boot's website. Since I only want to configure the logging information for now here is what my yml file looks like right now:

```
# ===================================================================
# SPRING BOOT PROPERTIES
# ===================================================================


# LOGGING
logging:
  config: /logback.xml # Location of the logging configuration file. For instance `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback
  logging.level.org.springFramework=DEBUG # Log levels severity mapping. For instance `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`
  path: # Location of the log file. For instance `/var/log`
  pattern:
    console: # Appender pattern for output to the console. Only supported with the default logback setup.
    file: # Appender pattern for output to the file. Only supported with the default logback setup.
    level: # Appender pattern for log level (default %5p). Only supported with the default logback setup.
```

But I have a few questions:

1. How much logging configuration should I do here in the yml file versus the `logback.xml` file? Should any logging configuration be put here at all versus putting it all in `logback.xml`?
2. Is the logging level configuration line written correctly?
3. Can I use another library's logging level, like logback? For example, could I put this: `ch.qos.logback.classic.Level=DEBUG`

Comment: [check the link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568780/4369820)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would not combine `logback.xml` with `application.yml`. Use either simplified configuration via `application.yml` if it is enough for you or use "fullfeatured" `logback.xml`.

To be honest I am not sure what will happen when you will have contradicting configuration in those two files (e.g. different patterns or log levels).

2 + 3. My guess is you have extra `logging` part. Correct example would be e.g.

```
logging:
  level:
    ch.qos.logback.classic: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: INFO
```